# URI Rewrite to Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, vhosts

I try to change URI to Subdomain. how to change `www.domain.com/auth/signin` to `login.domain.com`

i have virtualhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>
   DocumentRoot "path/to/root/public"
   ServerName domain.local
   ServerAlias *.domain.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
php_flag display_errors 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.local
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.local
RewriteRule ^login/?$ http://domain.local/auth/signin [P,L,QSA]
```

Comment: isn' your rule reversed ? RewriteRule ^auth/signin$ login.domain.com [P,L,QSA]

Comment: @R.Martin Still doesn't work. Please, try explaining how you mean

Answer (score 0):

**1: Standard http version:**

```
RewriteEngine On
php_flag display_errors 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

# If the url is not http://domain.local (Added [NC])
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.local [NC]

# If the url is not http://www.domain.local (Added [NC])
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.local [NC]

# Redirect
RewriteRule ^login(.*)$ http://domain.local/auth/signin$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

> http://sub1.domain.local/login to http://domain.local/auth/signin
>
> http://sub2.domain.local/login to http://domain.local/auth/signin
>
> http://sub2.domain.local/login?token=1 to http://domain.local/auth/signin?token=1

**2: (Optional) http or https detection**

```
RewriteEngine On
php_flag display_errors 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

# If the url is not http(s)://domain.local (Added [NC])
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.local [NC]

# If the url is not http(s)://www.domain.local (Added [NC])
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.local [NC]

# http or https detection
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s) 

# Redirect
RewriteRule ^login(.*)$ http%1://domain.local/auth/signin$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

> http://sub1.domain.local/login to http://domain.local/auth/signin
>
> https://sub1.domain.local/login to https://domain.local/auth/signin
>
> http://sub2.domain.local/login to http://domain.local/auth/signin
>
> https://sub2.domain.local/login to https://domain.local/auth/signin
>
> http://sub2.domain.local/login?token=1 to http://domain.local/auth/signin?token=1
>
> https://sub2.domain.local/login?token=1 to https://domain.local/auth/signin?token=1